# Error installing and using laravel mix

Tags: laravel-5, npm

I want to install Mix in laravel . I run "npm install --no-bin-links" in my IDE terminal or in CMD but I get this error: (my laravel version is 5.4.27)

D:\wamp64\www\laravelProject>npm install --no-bin-links
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-bin-links"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! D:\wamp64\www\laravelProject\npm-debug.log

Comment: Hey, I had the same error just now, probably some versions incompatibility?

Comment: I found the answer.
I updated the npm and everything was fine @DjuraMarinkov

Comment: That's it, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command helped me too:

`npm cache clean --force`

Also, you might need to add sudo in linux.

Answer (score 2):

I found!!

I remove node-modules then removed package-lock.json and ran